# IOS/Objective-C/Storyboard: Prevent ViewController From Launching Modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

I want a viewcontroller to launch using a show transition, not modally from the bottom.  Normally when I use the following code that's what happens.  However, in this case, it is launching as a modal controller from the bottom up.  Is there a switch I don't know about or could something be set in Storyboard that is causing this VC to launch modally from the bottom instead of showing?

```
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;

    IDImportEventsOnboard *importEvents =
    [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"importEventsOnboard"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: importEvents];

    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion: nil];
```

The VC is embedded in a navigation controller.

Should I be using showViewController directly to the targetVC without going through the Nav? Or a pushViewController What is a proper, robust way to show a VC with a show transition?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: When trying to show the importEvents controller are you already on a navigation controller? If so you could push it onto the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code you are 'presenting' a new NavigationController from a ViewController. In order to do a push/show transition, that needs to be done on an instance of a NavigationController. If your current ViewController is already in a NavigationController, you can push the new ViewController onto the current NavigationController stack. For Example:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;

IDImportEventsOnboard *importEventsVC =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"importEventsOnboard"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:importEventsVC animated:YES];
```